# Issue when scraping data on McMaster-Carr website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm writing a crawler for McMaster-Carr. For example, the page https://www.mcmaster.com/98173A200 , if I open the page directly in browser, I can view all the product data.

Because the data is in dynamically-loaded content, so I'm using Selenium + bs4.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://www.mcmaster.com/98173A200"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
    driver.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    delay = 20
    try:
        email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MainContent')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout loading DOM!")
    print(soup)
```

However, if I run the code I would get a [login dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQtwe.png), which I wouldn't get if I open this page directly in a browser like I mentioned.

I also tried logging in with the code below

```
   try:
        email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'Email')))
        print("Page is ready!!")
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")

    email_input.send_keys(email)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id('Password')
    password_input.send_keys(password)
    login_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("FormButton_primaryButton__1kNXY")
    login_button.click()
```

Then it shows [access restricted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4kW1.png).

I compared the requested header in the page opened by Selenium and the page in my browser, I couldn't find anything wrong. I also tried other webdrivers like PhantomJS and FireFox, and I got the same result.

I also tried using random user-agent using the code below

```
from random_user_agent.user_agent import  UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem

software_names = [SoftwareName.CHROME.value]
operating_systems = [OperatingSystem.WINDOWS.value, OperatingSystem.LINUX.value]

user_agent_rotator = UserAgent(software_names=software_names,
                               operating_systems=operating_systems,
                               limit=100)

user_agent = user_agent_rotator.get_random_user_agent()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=' + user_agent)
```

Still same result.

The developer tool in the page opened by Selenium showed there were a bunch of [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNX5A.png). I guess the tokenauthorization one is the key to this issue, but I don't know what should I do with it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. The reason you saw a login window is that you were accessing McMaster carr via a chrome driver. When the server recognizes your behaviour, it will require you to sign in.
2. A typical login wouldn't work if you haven't been authenticated by McMaster (need to sign NDA)
3. You should look into McMaster API. With the API, you can access the database directly. However, you need to sign an NDA with McMaster Carr before obtaining access to the API. https://www.mcmaster.com/help/api/

Comment: We need to scrap all the products data from Mcmaster. If we need all products information and details which are not available through APIs, Then Do we still need to contact MCMaster using "eCommerce@mcmaster.com" ?